# Comparar string com enum, dentro da lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda, enums

o problema é:

Tenho um dropdownlist carregado a partir de um enum, que pode vir com o valor nulo da tela.

```csharp
listaItensSolicitados = os.Site == null ? 
   this.itemSolicitadoService.Consultar(o =>
            o.ItemServico.Servico.Chave == 9 &&
            o.ChaveOrgao == os.Orgao.Chave && o.Numero.Contains(ramal)
            && o.CategoriaDiurna == ddlCategoriaDiurna
            && o.Instalado == true
            && (o.Depreciado == null
            || o.Depreciado == false)).Take(200).ToList() :
```

Como sabem, não da pra usar `ToString()` dentro da `lambda`, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de eu fazer essa comparação, no meu `ActionResult` eu recebo da tela o valor do `DDL` como `string`, e quando vem o valor `null`, não funciona.

@edit

Esse é o meu `enum`:

```csharp
public enum CategorizacaoRamaisEnum : int
{     
    [Description("Categoria 1")]
    Categoria1 = 1,
    [Description("Categoria 2")]
    Categoria2,
    [Description("Categoria 3")]
    Categoria3,
    [Description("Categoria 4")]
    Categoria4,
    [Description("Categoria 5")]
    Categoria5,
    [Description("Categoria 6")]
    Categoria6,
    [Description("Categoria 7")]
    Categoria7,
    [Description("Categoria 8")]
    Categoria8,
    [Description("Categoria 9")]
    Categoria9,
    [Description("Categoria 10")]
    Categoria10,
    [Description("Categoria 11")]
    Categoria11       
}
```

@edit 2

Criação do `dropdownlist`:

```csharp
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCategoriaDiurna", 
           (ViewBag.CategoriaDiurna as SelectList), 
            string.Empty)
```

Comment: `Como sabem, não da pra usar ToString` Eu não sei disso não, pode explicar melhor qual é o problema? Na verdade dizer onde está o problema, o que ocorre, o que deveria ocorrer, do que está falando.

Comment: Então, ToString ou qualquer conversão para string não funciona dentro do linq, por não existir algo parecido no banco de dados. O problema ocorre na linha que compara a CategoriaDiurna com a selecionada no dropdownlist que vem da tela. No caso o o.CategoriaDiurna é um Enum, e o ddlCategoriaDiurna é uma string, gostaria de saber como fazer a comparação disso dentro da lambda.

Comment: Está usando em banco de dados, já ajuda explicar. O `Enum` também não existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma :

Criei um metodo para buscar a string passada em tela no meu enum, caso fosse valor null, retornasse a categoria1 por padrão :

```
public CategorizacaoRamaisEnum retornarEnum(string ddlSelecionado) 
{
     return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlSelecionado) 
             ? CategorizacaoRamaisEnum.Categoria1 
             :(CategorizacaoRamaisEnum)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(CategorizacaoRamaisEnum),
               ddlSelecionado);
}
```

Validei o retorno e se o valor passado existia no `enum`:

```
CategorizacaoRamaisEnum retornoCategoriaDiurna = retornarEnum(ddlCategoriaDiurna);
bool result = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CategorizacaoRamaisEnum)).Contains(ddlCategoriaDiurna);
```

E finalmente na minha `query` `Linq`:

```
listaItensSolicitados = os.Site == null ?      this.itemSolicitadoService.Consultar(o =>
            o.ItemServico.Servico.Chave == 9 &&
            o.ChaveOrgao == os.Orgao.Chave
            && o.Numero.Contains(ramal)
            && o.Instalado == true          
            && (result ? o.CategoriaDiurna == retornoCategoriaDiurna : o.Instalado == true)
            && (o.Depreciado == null
            || o.Depreciado == false)).Take(200).ToList()
```

Sei que ficou redundante, no falso do ternário, mas dessa forma resolveu meu problema. Se alguém pensar em uma forma mais elegante, por gentileza posta ai, que vai me ajudar a melhorar.

Answer (score 2):

O valor deste ddlCategoriaDiurna vem **Categoria 1**, como exemplo?

Caso seja isto você poderia ler o valor `Description` do seu `enum`

```
public static string Descricao(this System.Enum itemEnum)
{
   DescriptionAttribute descricao = (DescriptionAttribute)itemEnum.GetType()
        .GetField(itemEnum.ToString())
          .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
        .FirstOrDefault();
   string retorno = itemEnum.ToString();
   if (descricao != null)
       retorno = descricao.Description;
   return retorno;
}
```

Em um `enum`

```
public enum Carro
{
    [Description("Carro Mercedes")]
    Mercedes,
    [Description("Carro Ferrari")]
    Ferrari,
    [Description("Carro Jaguar")]
    Jaguar,
    Porche
}
```

Um exemplo de uso com `lambda`

```
Carro[] carros = new []{ Carro.Ferrari, Carro.Jaguar };
string texto = Carro.Ferrari.Descricao();
// texto = "Carro Ferrari"
if (carros.Any(c => c.Descricao() == texto))
    Console.WriteLine("Correto");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Incorreto");

// Resultado: Correto
```

Comment: Sim, viria categoria1, como você mencionou, contudo o meu problema, é quando o usuário escolhe a opção Nula.

Comment: Coloquei na segunda edição agora, como eu crio o dropdownlist, no caso eu deixo a primeira opção como string.empty, para caso o usuário não queira utilizar esse filtro.

Comment: No seu exemplo você poderia colocar no local de o.CategoriaDiurna == ddlCategoriaDiurna. Para (ddlCategoriaDiurna == string.Empty || o.CategoriaDiurna == ddlCategoriaDiurna)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi o problema esta no fato de tu possuir um "enum" com strings.

1º ponto: Caso tu não informe explicitamente qual o valor daquele `enum` ele assume a ordem de lançamento e infere números

Exemplo:

```
enum Meses:short
{
    Janeiro,
    Fevereiro,
    ...
}
```

Neste caso os valores seria 0, 1 e assim por diante.

A melhor solução que posso te dar é mapear esse `enum` para um dicionário ou então criar uma classe `enum` com as strings que tu deseja comparar. Outra solução seria criar uma tabela auxiliar no banco para ter esses valores cadastrados lá, para caso eles puderem ser alterados ou adicionados e não deixar esse `enum hard coded`.

Comment: Eu já tenho o enum mapeado em uma tabela auxiliar no banco.